# Prove that system of equation implies statement

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, cubics

How to prove that

$$
\begin{cases}
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 & = 0 \\
x_1x_2 + x_2x_3 + x_3x_1 & = p \\
x_1x_2x_3 & = -q \\
x_1 & = 1/x_2 + 1/x_3
\end{cases}
$$

implies

$$
q^3 + pq + q = 0\,\,?
$$

Comment: Have you tried subbing in your values for p and q and then using the given identities?

Comment: First three are Vieta's formula. Not sure about last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote the equations by $(1),\ldots ,(4)$. Then $(4)$ says $x_1x_2x_3=x_2+x_3$ and $(3)$ says $x_1x_2x_3=-q$. This gives $x_3=-x_2-q$. Substitute this into $(1)$. This gives 
$x_1=q$.
 Then $q\cdot (2)-(3)$ gives $-q(p+q^2+1)=0$, or 
$$q^3+pq+q=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

According to the first three equations, $x_1, x_2, x_3$ are solutions of 
$$x^3 +px + q = 0$$

The fourth equation can be translated into $x_1x_2x_3 = x_3 + x_2$, i.e. $-q = -x_1$, then $x_1 = q$,

Conclude by noting that $q$ solves $x^3 +px + q = 0$